# GitHub Actions: run if

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to setup a custom action for GitHub Actions and currently this is what I have:

```
name: 'Install Dependencies'

inputs:
    os:
        description: 'The OS to fetch the dependencies for'
        required: True
    

runs:
    using: "composite"
    steps:
        - run: echo I am a test
          shell: bash
          if: startsWith(os, 'Linux')
```

What I am trying to do is to eventually have a bunch of different shell scripts that are tailored to do the job for a specific OS and therefore in my action, I want to select the appropriate script based on the `os` parameter that was passed into it.

When I am invoking the action as shown above though, I get `Unexpected value 'if'`. So my question is: How can I only run execute the `run` command if a condition is met?

Comment: Not supported as of Aug 2021 - https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/main/docs/adrs/0549-composite-run-steps.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to use a naming convention for your scripts and run call them with the name of the os:

```
myscript.$(os).sh
```

Comment: Nope the `if` still doesn't work. The example you showed was for specifying the job within a workflow, but I am trying to do this in an _action_ that can then be invoked from the workflow. Using such a naming scheme is actually a great idea though...

Comment: Hm yeah I guess that would be an option. However I wanted to create the action in order to not have to put all different cases into my main workflow and encapsulate it into a separate action instead... But I think I'll stick to the naming convention thing. So if you update your answer so that it only suggests that, I'll accept is as the correct one (don't want anyone to mistakenly assume that the `if` approach here was working) :)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use bash's `||` and negating the desired condition to ensure the command that follows is only executed if the condition is true (which is negated to false, which runs the command after `||`):

```yaml
- run: ${{ !startsWith(os, 'Linux') }} || echo "I am a test"
  shell: bash
```